# Can't find the "Using" options in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, using

This is probably a silly question, but I have looked and haven't found a straight forward answer for it. I started learning ASP.net recently, and started following a tutorial. i start by creating a project, an MVC2 web application, but when it starts, i cant find the "using system;" , "using system.web;" etc...What am i doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: where are you looking for it? do you already have some code in place that needs it?

Comment: the tutorial shows it on the top in the home controller, but all I see is this : <HandleError()> _
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Comment: Please tell me that you aren't typing "using system;" when you should be typing "using System;"

Comment: no, the project is completely new, i haven't added anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you are using VB.Net not C#. You should use `Import System` not `Using System;`.

In addition VB.Net allows for importing namespaces at the project level as opposed to needing to do it in every file. This is done through the project properties (References tab if I recall correctly). This means that the `Import System`, `Import System.Web`, etc. aren't needed in every file.

Comment: Or if you were intending to use C#, make sure that the project you select is from the C# menu and not the VB.NET menu